# UIButton adjust width to text width

Tags: ios, uibutton

i have the following code for a horizontal scrolling menu. But the text looks as follows (example):

mybutt...umber

i have the following code:

```
scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(categoryArray.count * 100 + 100, 50);
scroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
[scroll setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:0.6]];

UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(5,15,100,20); // position in the parent view and set the size of the button
[myButton setTitle:@"All" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton.titleLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
// heb ik toegevoegd
[myButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18]];
/////////////
[myButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
// add targets and actions
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(cmdCategroy:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[scroll addSubview:myButton];
myButton.tag = categoryArray.count + 1;


for (int y = 0; y < categoryArray.count; y++) {
    //NSLog(@"nb cat : %d",categoryArray.count);
    UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    myButton.frame = CGRectMake(100 + 5 + 100 * y,15,100,20); // position in the parent view and set the size of the button
    [myButton setTitle:[categoryArray objectAtIndex:y] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //[myButton sizeToFit];
    [myButton.titleLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    // heb ik toegevoegd
    [myButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18]];
    //stringsize.width
    /////////////
    [myButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    // add targets and actions
    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(cmdCategroy:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [scroll addSubview:myButton];
    myButton.tag = y;
}
```

How do i make the text not truncated and set the button width to the width of the text?

Comment: Tried [myButton sizeToFit]?

Comment: Calculate the size of the text for the given font and make your button big enough.

Answer (score 3):

You can use like this

```
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    NSString *str= @"your text";
    CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(300, 9999);

    UIFont *myFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MyriadPro-Regular" size:12];

    CGSize myStringSize = [str sizeWithFont:myFont
                          constrainedToSize:maximumSize
                              lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    myButton.frame=cgrectmake(button.frame.origin.x,button.frame.origin.y,mystringsize.width,button.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: tnx for the comment, but how do i do this in the existing code? Im new to this.

Comment: Plz see my edited answer and if still u not get plz let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, calculate the size width of your string and set the button frame to that. Here is a nice and short way of doing it.

```
    CGSize size = [myButton.titleLabel.text sizeWithAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:label.titleLabel.font forKey:NSFontAttributeName]];
    myButton.frame = CGRectMake(myButton.frame.origin.x,myButton.frame.origin.y, ceil(size.width), myButton.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: how do you do this in swift?